# Strongest possible kwonkicker jumping knee strike

Tags: science-based, biology, physics, xenobiology, biochemistry

How strong can the bones/plates and muscles of a humanoid be when pushing biology to its absolutely maximum limit to allow the fighter to deal the most powerful jumping knee strike physically possible without injuring itself by breaking it's own bones or plates,muscles and tendons or whatever anatomy it has.

and I'm Talking about a mid range straight strike without grabs and no rotations as in the picture [image]

Comment: How do you define 'strongest strike'? Highest velocity? Impulse? Impact force calculations are generally quite complicated and often get simplified to the point of them being pointless.

Comment: isn't the force factor precise enough? force equals mass multiplied by acceleration

Comment: Sure, you can calculate the force, given, say, the weight of a persons leg and the acceleration involved. But this number doesn't really tell you anything about what this kind of kick will to on impact...

Comment: This question does not seem to be about worldbuildilng. Also, this question would be much better asked on the martial arts SE (http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: martialarts.stackexchange includes all kinds of possible humanoids with varied hypothetical  anatomies?

Comment: MA.SE will at least answer you question with regards to humans. I'd also like to point out that at the time of this comment, nowhere in your question does it state anything about "all possible humanoids with varied hypothetical anatomies" - all you have is "bones/plates and muscles of a humanoid", and a picture of a **human** doing a jumping knee strike. Finally, this question still does not seem to be about worldbuilding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=maQINqPI7S0&t=6m) i saw about kicks in muay thai they show a low kick delivering a force of 1000 pounds force (lbf) [(conversion tabel here)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_(force))  They don't state this guy has the world record so i guess you can go somewhat higher but not a lot more. EDIT: I just realized you were specifically asking for knee kick. i don't know an example of that but Wolff's law as described below still has it's influence there.

This would probably shatter a normal persons shinbone, but because fighters like that kick so often their bones will get microfractures and grow thicker and stronger. This effect is called [wolff's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolff%27s_law)

I'm not entirely sure about tendons and muscle tissue but i think a similar growth applies on them with smal tearing regrowing stronger and thicker.

Comment: Seems like there is a lot of handwaving going on... What kind of impact *force* is this that is measured in pounds/kg?

Comment: @fgysin sorry my bad it was lbf which is a measurement for force. i don't know which part of you would call handwaving? But i can't find any example of a knee kick so it might not be of much use i suppose :)